# DateTime.Minute returns 5 instead of 05

Tags: c#, datetime, minute

The code below returns 5 in `MessageBox` because the minute is "05". I have used "mm" when to show it with leading 0. Why is this not working?

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(d.startTime.Month,d.startTime.Day,d.startTime.Year,15,05,00);
String s = date.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm");
d.startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(s);
MessageBox.Show(d.startTime.Minute.ToString());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're showing `ders.startTime.Minute`, not anything from the formatted string. Since `Minute` is an integer it outputs as `5`. Use

```
ders.startTime.ToString("mm"));
```

which will output only the `Minute` value of the datetime, formatted with the leading zero.

Answer (score 4):

`startTime.Minute` returns minute in integer, so thats why, you got `5`

Use
`startTime.Minute.ToString("D2");`

Comment: how can I get 05 then?

Comment: Format it, `.ToString("00")` is the simplest way, or just format the `DateTime` directly using `"mm"`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add a format string to your call to message box.

```
MessageBox.Show(d.startTime.Minute.ToString("00"));
```

You can find out more about them [on the msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y(v=vs.110).aspx)